# failing to get the response error message in ktor

Tags: kotlin, http, response, ktor

I'm trying to print the message returned from the post response request, when there is an error. So the message I get in postman, when I do a bad request is:

> {"Error": "This email is already in use!"}

Then I get the body() of it as follows:

```
return kotlin.runCatching {
            val response = client.post {
                url(HttpRoutes)
                contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                setBody(postRequest)
            }
                response.body()
        }
```

The expecting response is as follows:

```
    @Serializable
data class UserPostResponse (
    @SerialName("Activation")
    val activation: Map<String, String>? = null,
    @SerialName("Error")
    val error: Map<String, String>? = null
)
```

in my viewModel I launch that service and onFailure(which happens) I want to println(response.message). However, I'm getting the following error:

```
RESPONSE failed with exception: io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input: Unexpected JSON token at offset 9: Expected start of the object '{', but had ' ' instead at path: $.Error
```

please help!

Comment: You can use the `Logging` plugin or a traffic analyzer tool (Wireshark) to observe the server response to determine where the problem is.

Comment: well, Ima try my best ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of waiting

```
@Serializable
data class UserPostResponse (
    @SerialName("Activation")
    val activation: Map<String, String>? = null,
    @SerialName("Error")
    val error: Map<String, String>? = null
)
```

change the type from Map string -> String. The Json is already converting it to string